# Keep RegEx Pattern From Selecting a '-' at the Beginning of a Group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the portion of text inside of a shortcode that looks like this

```
[img:some-code-here-which-could-have-UPPER-case-and-0-9-numbers].
```

Questions
A: Will this ALWAYS working the way I intend?
B: How can I not select any text that starts with a dash?

```
\[img:{1}[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\]
```

My issue is this regex seems to work for 99% of what I want but the it still selects the following which it should not.

```
[img:-not-a-code]
```

Comment: `\[img:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\]`
starts with `[img:`, followed by at least one letter/digit, followed by any number of or no pairs of a single dash and at least one letter/digit, and ends with `]`.
`[` and `]` need to be escaped.
`[a-zA-Z0-9]` means: any of those (in ranges).
`+` means: at least one.
`*` means: any number of repeats (including none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this

```
\[img:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\]
```

But this matches with [img:x-------]. Don't know if it fits your need ?

In order to prevent more than one dash between words you could try

```
\[img:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\]
```

or

```
\[img:\w+(\-\w+)*\]
```

Comment: no it should not allow more than one dash per character.

Comment: How can I make it select global? using value.match('\[img:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\]/g'); returns null.

Comment: nm. I didn't realize you don't need quotes for regEx